# Retrofit Error: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 92 path $.belongs_to_collection

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I need to make a call to an api to receive details of a movie via an ID. When I make the first call, it works normally. If the second call has the same ID as the first call it also works, and so on if I am making the call with the same ID. Now, if I make the first call with one ID, and the second call with another ID, the application crashes and shows the following error:

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 92 path $.belongs_to_collection`

I looked for solutions here but none worked. Could you help me?
Below are the codes that I think are important.

```
Retrofit Interceptor

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val request = chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Authorization", Private.theMovieDatabaseHeaderAuthorization)
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
```

```
Retrofit Builder

private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        addInterceptor(TheMovieDatabaseInterceptor())
    }.build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Private.theMovieDatabaseBaseUrl)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

```
Retrofit Endpoint

@GET("movie/{movie_id}?language=en-US")
suspend fun getMovieDetails(@Path("movie_id") movieId: String): MovieDetailsModel
```

```
MovieDetailsModel

data class MovieDetailsModel(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("adult")
    val adult: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    val backdropPath: String,
    @SerializedName("belongs_to_collection")
    val belongsToCollection: String,
    @SerializedName("budget")
    val budget: Int,
    @SerializedName("genres")
    val genres: List<GenreModel>,
    @SerializedName("homepage")
    val homepage: String,
    @SerializedName("imdb_id")
    val imdbId: String,
    @SerializedName("original_language")
    val originalLanguage: String,
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    val originalTitle: String,
    @SerializedName("overview")
    val overview: String,
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    val popularity: Double,
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    val posterPath: String,
    @SerializedName("production_companies")
    val productionCompanies: List<CompanyModel>,
    @SerializedName("production_countries")
    val productionCountries: List<CountryModel>,
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    val releaseDate: String,
    @SerializedName("revenue")
    val revenue: Int,
    @SerializedName("runtime")
    val runtime: Int,
    @SerializedName("spoken_languages")
    val spokenLanguages: List<LanguageModel>,
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status: String,
    @SerializedName("tagline")
    val tagline: String,
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String,
    @SerializedName("video")
    val video: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    val voteAverage: Double,
    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    val voteCount: Int
)
```

```
Repository

override suspend fun getMovieDetails(movieId: String): MovieDetailsModel {
        return theMovieDatabaseEndpoints.getMovieDetails(movieId)
    }
```

```
ViewModel

private val _movieDetails: MutableLiveData<MovieDetailsModel> = MutableLiveData()
val movieDetails: LiveData<MovieDetailsModel> = _movieDetails

private fun getMovieDetails(movieId: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    Log.d("getMovieDetails", "movieId: $movieId")
    _movieDetails.value = theMovieDatabaseApiUseCase.getMovieDetails(movieId)
}
```

Comment: I suppose [this](https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/646bda3dd1857201403243f3?language=en) is the answer, `"belongs_to_collection"` is not actually `String`

Answer (score 0):

`belongs_to_collection` doesn't return a `String`, as the API Documentation says.

You can check more [here](https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/646bda3dd1857201403243f3?language=en).